# "Users in last 30 minutes" count is not what's expected

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Can someone please tell me the difference between "Users in last 30 minutes" and "Daily Active Users"?  For instance in our application, on friday evening around 6 PM, the last 30 min users had crossed the 10K mark, however, when the daily active was updated next day, it was still around the 7.7K mark. Can someone please clear out the definitions? Aren't these unique users in last 30 minutes? Also, do these users include the ones who just receive the push notification? Or the ones who open it? because the "Users in last 30 min" count goes higher than people who open the notification. Thanks.

Comment: Happened with me too. I think it is somehow related to the 'notification-receive' event of Firebase, as our User count shoots up whenever we're sending a stream of notifications, yet the DAU is not changed.